# how to capture the xmlout received in callback url

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I received like this data from  inspect->Network->Headers->Form Data

xmlmsg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message date="23/11/2020 08:58:05">
   <Language>eng</Language>
   <Version>1.0</Version>
   <Currency>524</Currency>
   <SessionId>E52DD6E8662CFE12A55A450732632110</SessionId>
   <ShopName>kaemp8848.com</ShopName>
   <FeeScr>0,00</FeeScr>
   <OrderID>36198</OrderID>
   <SessionID>E52DD6E8662CFE12A55A450732632110</SessionID>
   <RezultOperation>Transaction Result</RezultOperation>
   <OrderStatus>CANCELED</OrderStatus>
   <TotalAmount>4500</TotalAmount>
   <PurchaseAmount>4500</PurchaseAmount>
   <TotalAmountScr>45,00</TotalAmountScr>
   <TransactionType>Purchase</TransactionType>
   <PurchaseAmountScr>45,00</PurchaseAmountScr>
   <OrderIDEncrypted>@encrypted@1@AD584F41A724312D</OrderIDEncrypted>
   <OrderDescription>ID:2102</OrderDescription>
   <AcqFeeScr>0,00</AcqFeeScr>
   <CurrencyScr>Nepal Rupee</CurrencyScr>
   <CurrencyISOAlpha>NPR</CurrencyISOAlpha>
   <TranDateTime>23/11/2020 08:58:05</TranDateTime>
   <OrderStatusScr>CANCELED</OrderStatusScr>
</Message>
```

I need to capture & save, the xmlout that server sends along with callback url.
My code is

```
$postData = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = array();
parse_str($postData, $data);
var_dump($_POST);
```

output is :

```
array(1) { ["xmlmsg"]=> string(908) "eng1.0524 E52DD6E8662CFE12A55A450732632110kaemp8848.com0,0036198 E52DD6E8662CFE12A55A450732632110Transaction ResultCANCELED4500450045,00Purchase45,00@encrypted@1@AD584F41A724312DID:21020,00Nepal RupeeNPR23/11/2020 08:58:05CANCELED" }
```

how to split & save to database ?

Comment: I would suggest starting with [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), see how you get on with that and perhaps post a follow up question with the code and any issues you get stuck on.

Comment: $xml = simplexml_load_string($postData);
     var_dump($xml); 
The result is bool(false)

Comment: From your output of `$_POST`, it looks as though you should be doing `$xml = simplexml_load_string($_POST['xmlmsg']);` then try `echo $xml->asXML();`